# random zeroes in array output

Tags: java, arrays, zero

I'm Trying to get an array with the odd numbers between 1 and 10. Everything works fine except for these random zeroes that pop up as:

[0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 9]

Is There a way to stop this? Help is appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] array = new int[10];


    for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        if (x % 2 == 0) {

        }

        else {

            array[x] = x;

    }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

}

Comment: `9 == 3 * 3` (and is not prime), `2` is divisible by `2` (but **is** prime). In what way is this working fine? Did you mean **odd** numbers? `System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, 10).filter(x -> x % 2 != 0).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));`

Comment: there was a typo in the phrasing, I did mean odd. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE ARRAYLIST

```
int max = 10;
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int x = 0; x < max; x++) {
    if (x % 2 != 0) {
        array.add(x);
    }
}
System.out.println(array);
}
```

Output

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

And just a note, isPrime is not doing anything actually its a useless variable
And Prime search logic is not full either

Answer (score 0):

You are only filling in the array spots at array[x] so when it is not prime, the array location is just left as a 0.

Edit: fyi your code finds odd numbers not primes.

Comment: there was a typo in the phrasing, I did mean odd. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to solve the printing out problem, Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   int [] array = new int[10];
   boolean isPrime = true; // you haven't used this variable!

   for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
      if (x % 2 == 0) {
         isPrime = false; // do you really need this block?
      }

     else {
        array[x] = x;
        System.out.print(", "+x+"");  // print the prim every time you find it.
     }
   }
  //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
 }
}
```

However, *your code is **not** the **right** way to find the prim numbers.*

On the other hand, for printing an array contains only the prim numbers, you could add every prim number to a new array and print that array out.

Comment: there was a typo in the phrasing, I meant odd. I edited the original question. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be re-using a variable where you shouldn't. Your for loop only fills in the odd slots of the array with its index.

I would also recommend a list, like ArrayList, as opposed to a normal array.

Basically, I would suggest something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int max = 100;

    for (int x = 0; x < max; x++)
    {
        if (isPrime(x))
        {
            primeNumbers.add(Integer.valueOf(x));
        }
    }

    for (Integer i : primeNumbers)
    {
        System.out.print(i.intValue() + ", ");
    }
}

private static boolean isPrime(int number)
{
    for (int n = 2; n < number; n++)
    {
        if (number % n == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I don't know if the function for calculating prime numbers in exactly right, but it's pretty close if it's wrong.

*src for prime number calc: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/*

Comment: there was a typo in the phrasing, I meant odd. I edited the original question. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

For the numbers between `0` and `n` there will be one half that are even and one half that are odd, so you will only find `n / 2` odd numbers. You don't need a temporary variable, just test for `% 2 != 0` with something like,

```
final int n = 10;
int[] array = new int[n / 2];
for (int x = 0, pos = 0; x < n; x++) {
    if (x % 2 != 0) {
        array[pos] = x;
        pos++;
    }
}
```

**or**, in Java 8+, you could do it with an `IntStream.filter` like

```
int[] array = IntStream.range(0, n).filter(x -> x % 2 != 0).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Your array length needs to be shortened, there are only 5 odd numbers between 1 and 10. 2) Prime is useless in your case, so just add any odd to the index.
You an use an ArrayList as they will not allow any unfilled index to be init to 0, however, an array will assign a 0 to any index that is not assigned with a value.

```
int [] array = new int[5];
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
     if(x % 2 != 0) {
        array[x]=x
    }
}
```